# Mongodb data analysis and visualize tools

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am beginner in mongodb , am able to store data in monogodb but want to know best open source tools from which i can analyze mongo db data.
I tried with studio 3t , robomongo and mongo db compass.but not find good for database size of 3 GB.

Please recommend good tools from which i can visualize data and also able to export data.

Answer (score 2):

**MongoDB Compass** analyzes your documents and displays rich structures within your collections through an intuitive GUI. It allows you to quickly visualize and explore your schema to understand the frequency, types and ranges of fields in your data set.

**NoSQLBooster** for MongoDB (formerly MongoBooster) is a shell-centric cross-platform GUI tool for MongoDB v2.6-3.6, which provides fluent query builder, SQL query SQL Query, update-in-place, ES2017 syntax support and true intellisense experience.

Comment: thanks ,it solved my problem of query writing but how i can visualize large amount of data like graph or pie chart.

Comment: Try to use spagobi, Its a BI tool on there you can visualize data with different chart and graph

Comment: for spagobi what i have to download to run application , am using linux os.

Answer (score 1):

**Studio 3T** lets you do both. You can [visualize data](https://studio3t.com/whats-new/mongodb-schema-discovery/) through the Schema Explorer feature and [import/export data](https://studio3t.com/whats-new/how-to-import-and-export-mongodb-data-with-studio-3t/) in various formats.

Answer (score 1):

The tools listed in the other answers provide some good options for exploring data, but if you want to summarise or aggregate it and have control over the type of visualisation you should look at a tool like [MongoDB Charts](https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts). This provides a "drag and drop" approach to creating charts directly from MongoDB collections.